# How to test a function inside a React functional component that is triggered by a nested component

Tags: reactjs, testing

I have a main component with functions. This component renders two nested components and passes its own functions as parameters. So the functions inside my main component are triggered by calls from the nested components, and not events in the main component.

I want to test these functions in my main component and not the calls from the nested ones, but I cannot work out how to start this function or to spy on what happens inside this function. I am working with functional components, so most answers I have found that seem to work with classes, also seem not to work for my case. I am also using Jest, Enzyme and React 16.

This is Portada.js:

```
function Portada(){
    const [tareas, setTareas] = useLocalStorage("tareas", []) //a useState for an Array

    //this is the function I am trying to test
    function AgregarTarea(ent){
        var numero = ObtenerNuevoIndice()
        var objeto = {tarea: ent, id: numero, estado: false }
        setTareas(tareas => [...tareas, objeto]) 
    }

    //I want to make a mock for this function
    function ObtenerNuevoIndice() {//some code}

    return(
        <div className='Portada'>
            <h1 className='Titulo' data-testid="Portada" >Bienvenido a tu lista de tareas</h1>  
            //This is where my function is called
            <Entrada funcion={AgregarTarea}/>      
            <Tareas tareas={tareas} eliminar ={EliminarTarea} actualizar={ActualizarTarea}/>
        </div>            
    )
}
```

this is Portada.test.js:

```
import {screen, cleanup} from '@testing-library/react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Portada from '../Portada'; //this is the main component
import Entrada from '../../Entrada/Entrada'; //this is a nested component
import Tareas from '../../Tareas/Tareas'; //this is a nested component
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('Se probarán las funciones', () =>{
    test('se probará la función AgregarTareas', () =>{
        const wrapper = shallow(<Portada />);
        const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'AgregarTarea');
        wrapper()
        expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    })
})
```

The code above is my most recent attempt out of a LOT of attempts. Here the terminal indicates that 'wrapper' is null. I was expecting instance() to solve it, but it does not work. I think this only works with classes since they are like a mould (something that has a shape but it's empty?) I also added the line wrapper() in the hope that I could just call the function and make it not null. But since it did not work, now I suspect that it exists, but I just can't access its functions.

I have also tried to spy on variables, but so far I have concluded that it is not possible because I cannot find anything related to that. I tried mocking the nested functions, or directly using `expect().toBeCalled[...]` on them, but it has not worked either.

I tried to start the nested components, but I do not think it gave me any leads. I tried weird round-about methods, by mocking the whole nested component, the nested functions or even the whole main function, all with guides I found in other posts online. I had no luck at all.

Comment: You can't (because you're using a function-based component) and shouldn't (even if you _were_ using a class-based component) mock `ObtenerNuevoIndice` - it's an internal implementation detail, not a collaborator. Test the _behaviour_ - what's that function supposed to _do_? You could mock the child components, or just render them too if they're relatively simple, then simulate the appropriate interaction with them that invokes the callback.

Comment: Thank you for answer! As I said, I am really new at this. So I hope you can walk me through.

With 'test the behaviour' you mean that I should basically recreate the logic  and use mock for, for example, the functions that are called internally. Did I understood right?

About the callback. You said I could mock the nested components, in that case I would just make the mock that calls these functions. But if I render them (because they are pretty simple), how could I call the functions? That is mostly half of what I cannot figure out